# Change Constant value of RelativeLayout

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a `TableView` inside of a `RelativeLayout`:

```xml
<some code>
<RelativeLayout x:Name="relativeLayout">
<some code >

<TableView  x:Name="tableView" 
RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1, Constant=0}"

RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=banner, Property=Height, Factor=1,Constant=120}"

RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height, Factor=1, Constant=210}">

<some code>
```

I need to switch the Constant value of the TableView HeightConstraint  between 210 (in the portrait device orientation)  and 500 (in the Landscape device orientation).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Iam dooing nearly the same in my App by using "DynamicResource".
You can define them in your XAML and while running, change the values in Page codebehind file in C#.

But there seams to be a better solution now, yust have a look on:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual-state-manager